# How to select randomly elements from a tensor, with a condition on the elements to choose?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a tensor filled with 0 and 1. Now I want to randomly choose e.g. 50% of the elements which are equal to one. How do I do that?
For example I have the following tensor:

```
tensor = tf.constant([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
```

Now I want to randomly choose the coordinates of 50% of the elements which are equal to one (in this case, I want to choose 2 elements out of the 4). The resulting tensors could look like follows:

```
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: Could you provide code to reproduce your tensor?

Comment: What do you mean by "choose", getting the coordinates? If you are looking for tensor elements equal to one, you already know the values... What shape does your tensor have? Do you want "50% of those which are equal to 1" or "50% of the total tensor, but only chosen from those equal to one"?

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.

```
import numpy as np

tensor = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
percentage = 0.5

ones_indices = np.where(tensor==1)
ones_length = np.shape(ones_indices)[1]
random_indices = np.random.permutation(ones_length)
ones_indices[0][random_indices][:int(ones_length * percentage)]
```

Edit: With your definition of a tensor I have adjusted the code:

```
import numpy as np

tensor = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
percentage = 0.5

indices = np.where(tensor == 1)
length = np.shape(indices)[1]
random_idx = np.random.permutation(length)
random_idx = random_idx[:int(length * percentage)]
random_indices = (indices[0][random_idx], indices[1][random_idx])
z = np.zeros(np.shape(tensor), dtype=np.int64)
z[random_indices] = 1

# output
z
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This method does work, but the issue is the following: I rerun this function multiple times in one session, i.e. all the numpy commands are only executed once, as the "graph" in tensorflow is built. So in the second run, I get the same shuffling, because it is not written in tensorflow functions. Any suggestions how to do that in tensorflow?

Comment: Can you not also run this function multiple times then? If not, you can also make the `random_idx` in advance the same number of time you rerun it, with `length` the maximum you can encounter. In your example `length` would be be 9.